# jq how to use split with nested keys in single --arg

Tags: jq

I would like to pass a nested key to jq in an arg. Using a single `--arg key $mypath` fails.

Looking at other questions it seems `split` is the correct method, but I cant find a basic example that works.

```
mypath="level1.level2.level3"
//working hardcode
jq '.level1.level2.level3' $myfile

//variations tried
jq --arg nest "${mypath}" '.[$nest]' $myfile
jq --arg nest "${mypath}" '.[$nest]|split(".")' $myfile
jq --arg nest "${mypath}" '.|split(".")|[$nest]' $myfile
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need [`getpath/1`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#getpath(PATHS)) for this. The method takes an array of paths to a particular node and returns the value present at it

```
jq --arg nest "$mypath" 'getpath($nest|split("."))'
```

Comment: thanks for the quick response